# Is Kakeya conjecture open with some additional regularity condition on Kakeya map?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hausdorff-dimension

in the paper, [ON KAKEYA MAPS WITH REGULARITY ASSUMPTIONS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.09108.pdf), the author of the paper consider the Kakeya conjecture with some regularity on Kakeya map,

> **Kekeya conjecture**[Hausdorff dimension version]
> If a set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ contains a unit line segment in each direction (such a set is called a Kakeya set), then $K$ has Hausdorff dimension $n$.

> **Definition of Kakeya map**. For any function $c: S^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n},$ we consider the associated map $\phi_{c}$
> $$
> \phi_{c}: S^{n-1} \times[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}, \quad(v, t) \mapsto c(v)+t v
> $$
> We call $\phi_{c}$ a Kakeya map, and $K_{c}:=\operatorname{Im}\left(\phi_{c}\right)=\bigcup_{v \in S^{n-1}} c(v)+[0,1] \cdot v$ the associated Kakeya set.

Then the authors of  this paper claim the following theorem:

> **Theorem1**. If $c: \overline{B^{n-1}(0,1)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is $\alpha$ - Hölder continuous for some $\alpha>\frac{(n-2) n}{(n-1)^{2}},$ then $\operatorname{Im}\left(\phi_{c}\right)$
> has positive Lebesgue measure.

> **Remark:** the endpoint of $\alpha$ is very close to 1 when $n$ is large, and when $\alpha=1$, this is to say Kakeya map is Lipschitz function and use the method in final remark we can get the conclusion.

> **Theorem2**. If $c: \overline{B^{n-1}(0,1)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is continuous and in $H^{s}\left(\overline{B^{n-1}(0,1)}\right)$ for some $s>(n-1) / 2$,
> then $\operatorname{Im}\left(\phi_{c}\right)$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

The proof of the paper use winder number and isoperimetric inequality. But there is no reference for the previous work in this direction, that is, add some regularity on Kakeya conjecture and try to go further.

The problem is,

> **Problem 1:** are there some similar papers in this direction?

and one more problem is,

> **Problem 2:** why when adding $L^1_{loc}$ condition on Kakeya map, then for any given open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the preimage in $S^{n-1}$ is a measurable set, then it gives some Stickiness on different scales on the discretization problem,  in this case, Kakeya problem is still hard? It seems we can get some more information on the multi-scale induction automatically.

There is some remark.

> **Remark**
> $T_{\theta}^{\delta}(c(\theta))$ is the cylinder with length 1 . radius $\delta$, direction $\theta$ and startpoint $c(\theta)$, $c$ is the kakeya map. for a fix scale $\epsilon$, $\bigcup_{i \in I_{\epsilon}} B_{\epsilon}\left(\theta_{i}\right)$ is a covering of $S^{n-1}$. If the sigularity of the matrix(this is autogiven in dimension 2)
> $$
> \left(\mu\left(T_{\theta_{i}}^{\varepsilon}\left(c\left(\theta_{i}\right)\right) \cap T_{\theta_{j}}^{\varepsilon}\left(c\left(\theta_{j}\right)\right)\right)\right)_{\left|I_{\varepsilon}\right| \times \left|I_{\varepsilon}\right|}
> $$
> has control, then by the intermediate dimension trick and a inclusion-exclusion principle estimate we can get at this scale $\epsilon$ a "n-dimension" lower bound estimate for $\mu(\cup_{\theta_i\in I_{\epsilon}}T_{\theta_{i}}^{\varepsilon}(c(\theta_i)))$. And this can be done in two dimension and multi-scale method can give us some help on establish such a estimate in dimension $n\geq 3$. If we know some  Stickiness on different scales, the Stickiness should be, for $\epsilon_2<< \epsilon_1$,
> \begin{equation}
> \liminf_{\epsilon_1\to 0, \epsilon_2\to 0}\inf_{\theta_0\in I_{\epsilon_1}}\frac{\#\left\{\theta \in I_{\varepsilon_{2}} \mid B_{\varepsilon_{2}}(\theta) \subseteq B_{\varepsilon_{1}}\left(\theta_{0}\right) \subseteq S^{n-1}, \begin{equation}
> d\left(\left(c(\theta), c\left(\theta_{0}\right)\right)) \lesssim \varepsilon_{1}\right.
> \end{equation} \right)}{\#\left\{\theta \in I_{\varepsilon_{2}} \mid B_{\varepsilon_{2}}(\theta) \subseteq B_{\varepsilon_{1}}\left(\theta_{0}\right) \subseteq S^{n-1}\right)}\geq \lambda>0
> \end{equation}
> And when adding $L_{l o c}^{1}$ condition on Kakeya map, we automatically have some Stickiness estimate, although not good enough, this make the Kakeya problem seems to be easier in this case.

Thanks in advance.